# Centering fixed button inside a div

Tags: html, css, position, css-position

I have a div with some elements inside.

[image]

I would like to center the start button exactly in the middle of the div. I've tried making it fixed like this:

**Board.css**

```
.board{
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 150px auto 0;
    border: 5px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: darkgray;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.startButton {
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    top:50%;
}

@media(max-width: 650px) {
    .board {
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
        margin: 150px auto 0;
        border: 5px solid black;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }
}
```

But as you can see, it is not perfectly aligned in the middle. How do I go about this? I've also made a media-query that makes the div smaller on smaller devices, so it needs to be responsive as well.

**Board.js**

```
render() {


    return (
        <div className="board">
            <button className="startButton">Start Game!</button>
            <Square clicked={this.squareClickedHandler} val={this.state.squareOne} />
            <Square clicked={this.squareClickedHandler} val={this.state.squareTwo} />
            <Square clicked={this.squareClickedHandler} val={this.state.squareThree} />
            <Square clicked={this.squareClickedHandler} val={this.state.squareFour} />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: share full code

Comment: try deleting all of button css properties and put margin:auto

Comment: Add `.startButton { transform: translate(-50%, -50%); }`.

Comment: @TemaniAfif I've added some extra code.

Comment: Use transform-origin: 50% 50%; in the startButton class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `position: relative;` in `.board` class and remove all css styles from `.startButton` and add following code in `.startButton`

```
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

Try following code

```css
.board{
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 150px auto 0;
    border: 5px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: darkgray;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    
}

.startButton {
   position: absolute;
   left: 50%;
   top: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

@media(max-width: 650px) {
    .board {
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
        margin: 150px auto 0;
        border: 5px solid black;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="board">
  <button class="startButton">Start Game!</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`left: 50%`
makes the element's x-coördinate be in the middle of your screen.

The value you actually want is

´left: (50% - [element width / 2]) ´

so your the x-coördinate will be a little to the left of the middle so your element can be in the middle